# WebQuiz compilation and html output file empty

Tags: html, javascript, webquiz

I'm working on the WebQuiz package.
I started with first example given by the reference document webquiz.pdf.
After pdflatex compilation of my first example (Quiz-1.tex), I get the pdf output document and it's ok (as explained on WebQuiz.pdf reference). But when I made the webquiz compilation (webquiz Quiz-1.tex), I get the html output document but a little empty (see figure please, displayed by Safari).
I checked on the Safari preferences and the Javascript is active.
Could'you please help me ? Thank you very much.

[image]

```
 \documentclass[language=french]{webquiz}
 \title{Quiz Français}
 \title{An easy example}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{question} % a quiz question
      Sous forme inéquation, $x \in[1,2] $ s'écrit aussi
    \begin{choice}[columns=2]
      \correct $1\le x\le 2$
      \incorrect $1\ge x\ge 2$
      \feedback l'ordre croissant est-il respecté? 
      \incorrect $1<x<2$
      \feedback l' intervalle est-il ouvert ou ferme\'e? 
      \incorrect $1<x\le 2$
      \feedback Les bornes sont-elles incluses ou exclues?
     \end{choice}
    \end{question}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you AndréC, for editing help.

Comment: Most likely this is an initialisation problem. Let's continue the discussion offline.

Comment: Thanks for your Email. I'll try your advices today.